# Attaching specific files based on the user's selection in a userform

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments, outlook-2010

For the next part of this project that I've been working on to speed up follow up emails to clients for the office, I'm looking to grab a specific attachment from a specified filepath based on the items that the user selected on the userform. These emails will always be sending the exact same files so the less time the user has to spend manually attaching files, the better it will be. My first assumption right off the bat was that I'd need a loop to do this, so I began to do my groundwork, but now I'm generally stuck.

The first loop grabs what the user selected from the userform:

```
    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
        If List1.Selected(i) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            msg = msg & "<font style = 'background: yellow'>" & List1.List(i) & "<br />"
        Else: If Counter = 0 Then End
    End If
    Next
```

And the second loop attaches the files based on the selections above:

```
    For i = 0 To List1.ListCount - 1
        If List1.Selected(i) Then
            Counter = Counter + 1
            .Attachments.Add List1.List(i)
        Else: If Counter = 0 Then End
    End If
    Next
```

The attachments process just fine.However, the program ends up displaying the highlighted body of the message as the filepath I tried to associate with the list item:

```
' test files
List1.List(0) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex1.py"
List1.List(1) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex2.py"
List1.List(2) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex3.py"
List1.List(3) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex4.py"
List1.List(4) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex5.py"
List1.List(5) = "C:\Users\jmarkman\Dropbox\Python Practice\ex6.py"
```

So my question is, how do I associate these file paths with corresponding items in the listbox within the userform? I'm pretty sure that although it worked, the process changed the list items since I assigned them a different value.

I'm not sure how complex or simple this might end up being, so your time and patience are well appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

People have said that one can learn best just by doing and making mistakes, but let me tell you that not having someone you can at least talk to about where to start making mistakes is incredibly frustrating. I hope anyone else who, like me, was on the cusp of solving this problem is able to look here and have their own "a-ha!" moment.

When I first asked this question, I was on the right path with choosing to put all of my filepath locations within an array and I was further along the right path by using a loop to go through it. I declared the myAttach array with a range as I did at first, but unlike whatever example I saw during my google research, I kept my second attachment loop the same but simply changed out List1.List(i) for myAttach(i). That made the script's wheels turn and performed all the functions I needed it to.

**The long and short of it was that I made an array that matched the quantity and order of the items in the userform and re-used the loop I made for picking the subjectivities, I was able to associate the choices in the userform to those in the array by having the second loop go through the array. Each listing in the array had a filepath associated with it.**

```
' example
myAttach(0) = "[filepath]"
myAttach(1) = "[filepath]"
myAttach(2) = "[filepath]"
myAttach(3) = "[filepath]"
' ... and so on ...
```

It helped to visualize the array and the list items as two side-by-side columns; the first item in the list is parallel to the first item in the array, and can therefore be recognized by the second loop. If a mental image isn't forthcoming, try inputting some data into two or more Excel columns to witness the relationship or review [Matricies](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/matrices.htm).

A caveat of this line-up approach, I found out shortly after while continuing research to figure out exactly what I did right *this time* would be if I had to have the items in the list in a specific order (i.e., alphabetical), but fortunately the list items are phrases and complete sentences and don't require sorting.

Happy learning and programming!